# rand() function producing same output every time C

Tags: c, visual-studio, random

I am trying to generate random numbers from 0 to 3 with the `rand()` function, and it works decently, but I have noticed something odd.

The function keeps producing the same pattern of numbers every time I run and rerun the project.

This is the code I am using broken down as simple as possible..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
int randomNumber;

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    randomNumber = rand() % 4;
    printf("%d ", randomNumber);
}

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

And this prints 15 random numbers from 0 to 3, and for me this is what I get

`1 3 2 0 1 0 2 2 2 0 1 1 1 3 1`

So this is fine. But the issue is, every single time I run the program this exact same thing prints.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a random number in computer science. Therefore to generate different outputs we must use pseudo-random. To do this write `srand(time(0))` where you have declared your variables.

Comment: There are random numbers, practically and to the best of our knowledge. Some processors have built-in hardware to collect thermal noise and provide random data, and there are other techniques for gathering random data.

Comment: I want a random number to be generated many times in a loop, doesn't `srand(time(0))` only work one time per run?

Comment: Eric, there is a difference between random and unpredictable

Comment: @TiborUkropina: As I wrote, to the best of our knowledge, we have both.

Comment: @brent_mb, I ran the code and it worked fine for me...

Comment: @EricPostpischil that is true, just a debate for another time

Comment: @TiborUkropina did you run it multiple times? My issue is it continues to produce the same output.

Comment: @brent_mb I ran it 5 times and got different results each time, where are you running your code from?

Comment: @brent_mb Assuming you correctly called `srand()` **once** in your code, note that `time()` only has a resolution in seconds. If you rerun your program quickly you might be getting the same seed value (and the same random sequence).